# Dockerfileでanyenvのインストールを記述したがパスが反映されない

Tags: docker, nodenv

anyenvをインストールしたコンテナを作成するDockerfileを書いています。

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt update
RUN apt -y upgrade
RUN apt install -y sudo git
RUN git clone https://github.com/anyenv/anyenv ~/.anyenv
RUN echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.anyenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
RUN echo 'eval "$(anyenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
RUN exec $SHELL -l
RUN anyenv install  --init
```

上記を実行するとエラーが発生しました。

```
=> [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                        0.1s 
=> => transferring dockerfile: 541B                                                                                                                                        0.0s 
=> [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                           0.0s 
=> => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                             0.0s 
=> [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:latest                                                                                                            0.0s 
=> [1/9] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:latest                                                                                                                              0.0s 
=> CACHED [2/9] RUN apt update                                                                                                                                             0.0s 
=> CACHED [3/9] RUN apt -y upgrade                                                                                                                                         0.0s 
=> CACHED [4/9] RUN apt install -y sudo git                                                                                                                                0.0s 
=> CACHED [5/9] RUN git clone https://github.com/anyenv/anyenv ~/.anyenv                                                                                                   0.0s 
=> CACHED [6/9] RUN echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.anyenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile                                                                                        0.0s 
=> CACHED [7/9] RUN echo 'eval "$(anyenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile                                                                                                      0.0s 
=> ERROR [8/9] RUN exec $SHELL -l 
------
 > [8/9] RUN exec $SHELL -l:
#11 0.414 /bin/sh: 1: exec: -l: not found
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c exec $SHELL -l]: exit code: 127
```

エラーメッセージは exec,-l がないと言っているようですが、どうすればいいの？という状態です。

anyenvのインストール手順は以下のサイトを参考にしています

[anyenvの環境構築 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/282Haniwa/items/71a48a10952413416d18)

**環境**

Docker version 20.10.7

#### 試したこと

**1.エラー直前までのImageを作成し、以降起動したコンテナ内で手動でコマンドを実行する**
下記でビルドするとビルド成功

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt update
RUN apt -y upgrade
RUN apt install -y sudo git
RUN git clone https://github.com/anyenv/anyenv ~/.anyenv
RUN echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.anyenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
RUN echo 'eval "$(anyenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

パスを確認するとない

```
root@6543e84c449a:/# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

シェルを再起動

```
root@6543e84c449a:/# exec $SHELL -l
ANYENV_DEFINITION_ROOT(/root/.config/anyenv/anyenv-install) doesn't exist. You can initialize it by:
> anyenv install --init
```

もう一度パスを確認すると設定できている

```
root@6543e84c449a:/# echo $PATH
/root/.anyenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

anyenvのインストール完了

```
root@6543e84c449a:/# anyenv install --init
Manifest directory doesn't exist: /root/.config/anyenv/anyenv-install
Do you want to checkout https://github.com/anyenv/anyenv-install.git? [y/N]: y
Cloning https://github.com/anyenv/anyenv-install.git master to /root/.config/anyenv/anyenv-install...
Cloning into '/root/.config/anyenv/anyenv-install'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 62, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
remote: Total 62 (delta 1), reused 1 (delta 0), pack-reused 57
Unpacking objects: 100% (62/62), 10.50 KiB | 155.00 KiB/s, done.

Completed!
```

**2.anyenvのフルパスを指定してコマンドを実行する**
下記でビルドするとビルド成功

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt update
RUN apt -y upgrade
RUN apt install -y sudo git
RUN git clone https://github.com/anyenv/anyenv ~/.anyenv
RUN echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.anyenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
RUN echo 'eval "$(anyenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
RUN ~/.anyenv/bin/anyenv install --force-init
```

ただし、この方法だと、以降anyenvコマンドすべてフルパスを記述することになります。
これは、Dockerfileとしては不適切な気がします。

**3.ENVでパスを設定する**
下記でビルドするとビルドエラー

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt update
RUN apt -y upgrade
RUN apt install -y sudo git
RUN git clone https://github.com/anyenv/anyenv ~/.anyenv
ENV PATH $HOME/.anyenv/bin:$PATH
RUN anyenv install --init
```

パスが反映されてないためanyenvが見つからないとなりました

```
=> [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                        0.1s 
 => => transferring dockerfile: 545B                                                                                                                                        0.0s 
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                           0.1s 
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                             0.0s 
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:latest                                                                                                            0.0s 
 => [1/6] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:latest                                                                                                                              0.0s 
 => CACHED [2/6] RUN apt update                                                                                                                                             0.0s 
 => CACHED [3/6] RUN apt -y upgrade                                                                                                                                         0.0s 
 => CACHED [4/6] RUN apt install -y sudo git                                                                                                                                0.0s 
 => CACHED [5/6] RUN git clone https://github.com/anyenv/anyenv ~/.anyenv                                                                                                   0.0s 
 => ERROR [6/6] RUN anyenv install  --init                                                                                                                                  0.5s 
------
 > [6/6] RUN anyenv install  --init:
#9 0.425 /bin/sh: 1: anyenv: not found
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c anyenv install  --init]: exit code: 127
```

```
exec $SHELL -l
```

このコマンドさえエラーにならなければ、問題ないと思いますが、
調べても有益な情報が見つけることができませんでした。
わかる方がいらっしゃれば、ご教示頂きたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: Dockerfile でエラーになる行を `RUN exec /bin/bash -l` に置き換えるとどうなりますか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！
試してみましたが、RUN exec /bin/bash -l　はエラーにならなかったものの、anyenvコマンドが見つからないというエラーになりました